# How to insert extra column

Tags: vba, excel

the folowing code allows me to browse for multiple different excel files and paste them in a single sheet below each other.the excel file have the same column names but have different data in them and is working fine, my problem is i need it when it paste a file it must also create extra column and write the name of that file in that column for each and every file it paste.

```
Sub Button5_Click()
 Dim fileStr As Variant
 Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet

 fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="microsoft excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Get File", MultiSelect:=True)
 Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
 Set ws1 = wbk1.Sheets("Sheet3")

 'handling first file seperately
 MsgBox fileStr(1), , GetFileName(CStr(fileStr(1)))
 Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(fileStr(1))
 wbk2.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ws1.Cells(ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2, 1)

 wbk2.Close

 For i = 2 To UBound(fileStr)
 MsgBox fileStr(i), , GetFileName(CStr(fileStr(i)))

 Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(fileStr(i))
 'using offset to skip the header - not the best solution,  but a quick one

 wbk2.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Copy ws1.Cells(ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2, 1)

 wbk2.Close
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Insert` method of a `Range` object to insert a column:

```
'***** Inserts new column to the left of column C
Range("C:C").Insert
```

Entering text in a cell:

```
'***** Entering text in A1
ws1.Cells(1, 1).Value = fileStr(i)
```

Comment: We also looking for inserting file names in that newcolumn...and please we dont do hard coding.

Comment: So where do you want the column? It was an example.

Comment: at the end of each data that has been inserted

Comment: I was under the impression that the column names and count were constant - in that case you know the last column. Are you pasting new data below the old or to the right of the old? (BTW your code is dependent on other code so I can't test it easily - `GetFileName`?)

Comment: GetFileName is a Function which I didnt paste it here...and I'm pasting below

Comment: Do you really need a new column? `wbk2.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1).Value = "Some string"` would insert "Some string" in row 1 and to the right of the last column used.

Comment: No man...I think you do not understand me.....I need to insert file names into a new column..

Comment: Yes, but writing text in a blank column to the right would produce the same result. In other words, what I don't understand is where you want the new column - to the right of the last used column? Or in a specific column that can be adressed like the example in my answer?

Comment: Let leave out the new column now...please help me on inserting a filename into a column

Comment: Updated answer with example of entering text in to a cell. Again an example which need sto be updated with the correct address: `Cells([Row], [Column]).Value` will update any cell that you want. You need to find out which! :)

Comment: If you do not want the fullpath, but the workbook name only, you can use wbk1.name/wbk2.name